# Custom UIPickerView Background

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uipickerview

So I want to change the UIPickerView background to add a black rectangle next to the white part of the scroller, a la the Convert app. 
[image]

However I'm not sure how to go about doing that. I know there's no direct way to do it, but I've also looked at trying to write my own UIPickerView from scratch using UIScrollView. This didn't seem very promising.

Do you have any suggestions or tips? Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a UIImageView that contains the left portion of your graphic above.  Add that UIImageView to the same view that contains your UIPickerView-- so it will draw on top of your UIPickerView.

Comment: What do you do about the border?